# Blender Script Not Applying Alpha Texture Correctly

Tags: python, command-line-interface, blender

I'm working on a Python script for Blender to apply textures to a model, including an alpha texture for transparency. However, the alpha texture doesn't seem to affect the material's transparency. Here's the part of my script where I apply the alpha texture:

```py
def create_texture_node(node_tree: bpy.types.NodeTree, path: str, is_color_data: bool, is_alpha: bool = False) -> bpy.types.Node:
    texture_node = node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')

    texture_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(path)

    if is_alpha:
        texture_node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True  # Treat alpha map as non-color data
    else:
        texture_node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = not is_color_data

    return texture_node
```

```
output_node = node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
principled_node = node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
node_tree.links.new(principled_node.outputs['BSDF'], output_node.inputs['Surface'])

coord_node = node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexCoord')
mapping_node = node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMapping')
mapping_node.vector_type = 'TEXTURE'

if alpha_texture_path != "":
    alpha_texture_node = create_texture_node(node_tree, alpha_texture_path, False, True)
    node_tree.links.new(mapping_node.outputs['Vector'], alpha_texture_node.inputs['Vector'])
    node_tree.links.new(alpha_texture_node.outputs['Color'], principled_node.inputs['Alpha'])
```

I expect this to make certain parts of the material transparent based on the alpha texture, but the entire material remains opaque. I've checked the texture, and it is a grayscale image(L). Any suggestions on why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Although this is a valid question here on SO I think you will get a faster answer over at [blender.se]